# Jackson - objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping puts package name in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I've complex (nested and custom classes) object to be serialized and deserialized.

I used 
`objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);`

Serialized Json looks like -
`{"@class":com.hello.www.domain.entities.foo.domain.impl.FProduct","flightTrip":{".....`

and we use deserialized version models at - `com.hello.www.domain.entities.trip.dto.models.FProduct`

Now, after deserializing it says -

`Class com.hello.www.domain.entities.foo.domain.impl.FProduct not subtype of [simple type, class com.hello.www.domain.entities.trip.dto.models.FProduct]`

This is assuming the classes at serialization would be present in same package while deserialization, which could not be true.

PS: I used 'enableDefaultTyping' because we have interfaces with multiple implementations, and we need to have polymorphic deserialization.